# PHP variable scope between various template files

Tags: php, templates, variables, scope

This is a newbie question, and I know it.

Template structure is your usual index.php, with a few require_once()'s for the header/footer etc.

I define a var at the top of index.php before any of the require_once()'s for the base url, such as $url = 'http://url';

I then want to echo this out into all template files, header/index/footer etc, it works inside index.php as expected, but fails with a undefined var in all template files that are included in.

I know it's a var scope issue, but I'm totally perplexed how to fix it.

I'm aware that the manual says vars are available to included files, however they aren't. Could it be a issue with my local PHP install?

edit : Created a couple of test files, and a var is defined between 2 files, so why are they not working on my main site files?

Any helps gracefully recieved.

Many Thanks

Comment: You need to show us how you invoke the templates. If there's a helper function in between the `$url=` declaration and the `include()` statement, you enter a new scope.

Comment: I just simplified it down to the bare minimum with a basic include($var.'header.php') then attempted to echo the $var on line 1 in header.php and it's still coming back as undefined when run. Really odd.

Comment: Solution found here http://drupal.org/node/84410

Comment: That means your description was a lie. You're not including a file, you're loading a remote resource.

Answer (score 1):

if you use functions or methods (functions in classes) then you need to do `global $variable` inside the function. Otherwise you will not have access to it, you also could define it as constant. A constant is always global.

```
define('MYURL', $url);
```

You might want to use a PHP framework, if you not already do so.